# How to get differences of dates

Tags: c#, ajax

I am making a web page in that I have used Ajax calendar to pick two date like `TO` date and `From` date and I also have a `Textbox` of total days.

So when user selects `to` and `from` dates, the difference of these dates is displayed in the textbox. So how can I find the difference of these dates..?

I set the format like `dd/MM/yyyy`.

e.g.

```
one textbox has: 20/04/2012  
second has     : 02/05/2012
```

So, please find difference on these ?

Thanks in Advance....
Mitesh

Comment: Please check my removal of AJAX tag (assuming you want to do it server side as tagged with C#). If you need it browser side - add JavaScript tag and possible ajax.

Comment: yes when to date is select and then from_date is select, direct diff. is displayed in next textbox of total days. i want to do at sever side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substraction operator (-) works on DateTime

```
DateTime to_datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(to_textbox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime from_datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(from_textbox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Timespan result  = to_datetime - from_datetime;
```

You can use it as

```
textBox1.Text = (to_datetime - from_datetime).TotalDays.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your textbox values to date using:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox2.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use [TimeSpane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
    TimeSpan ts = dt1.Subtract(dt2);
    Console.Write(ts.TotalDays);
    textBox3.Text = ts.TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C# code: DateTime support "-" that results in TimeSpan object.

```
DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterday = nowTime.AddDay(-1);
TimeSpan diff = nowTime - yesterday;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date1 =DateTime.ParseExact("20/04/2012","d/M/yyyy",null);
 DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact("02/05/2012", "d/M/yyyy", null); 
 TimeSpan datediff = date2 - date1;
 Response.Write(datediff.ToString());
```